# How to export JFrame in High resolution?

Tags: java

I created a Jframe and now I want to export this. But it is alway in low resolution.

Export:

```
public void exportImageVersion1(JFrame frame) {
        try
        {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics();
            frame.paint(graphics2D);
            ImageIO.write(image,"tiff",new File("test12.tiff"));
          
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not enough details.  What are the values returned by `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`?

Comment: both 500 pixels

Comment: Well, if you specify 500x500 for your buffered image, that’s what you will get. What is the pixel size of the frame? What do you mean by “high resolution”?

Comment: Oww, I see the problem. so if I want to make 1920 x 1080 i have to set the pixels to 1920 x 1080?

Comment: Did you try it?